FastAPI routers do not detect initialized collections using beanie
I have a big application in Python 3.11, but I've narrowed the problem into a smaller example to demonstrate, and I get the same error.
Assuming I have a class called Product which is a Document:
# /models/product.py
from beanie import Document

class Product(Document):
    ...
    class Settings:
       name = "mycollection"

In my main.py file I initialize the FastAPI app and give it a lifespan as such (ommitting imports for simplicity)
# main.py
...

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan)

@app.get('/inside_app')
def inside_app(product: Product):
   return 1

app.include_router(product_router)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   uvicorn.run(app)

# /controllers/product.py

product_router = APIRouter(prefix='/product')

@product_router.get('/inside_product')
def product(product: Product):
    return 1

The lifespan is defined in:
# database_initialization.py

async def initialize_database():
    client = AsyncIOMotorClient(...)
    await init_beanie(database=client.get_database("db_name"), document_models=[Product])


@asynccontextmanager
def lifespan(_app: FastAPI)
    await initialize_database()
    yield


The problem is that when I use postman and make a GET request to localhost:8000/inside_app it works just fine without errors. However, when I make a GET reuqest to localhost:8000/product/inside_product I get:
beanie.exception.CollectionWasNotInitialized

Why is that? I also tried to add the lifespan to the product_router as well, and I still get the same error...
I would appreciate any help, thanks!

If you check the Beanie documentation, you'll see that the parameter document_model in your code is incorrect. The correct parameter is actually document_models. I believe that if you try it this way, your code will run successfully.

Sorry, the actual code had document_models in the first place (and not document_model) so it isn't the solution, also it is not a valid argument and would be highlighted/raise an exception before initialization... Do you have another approach? Thanks!

Ok the problem was in the imports. I marked src as the source directory in pycharm and imported as such:
from src.x.y.z import ...

Which lead to the error. Removing the src. from the import fixed the issue.
Pay attention to the imports while marking src as a source directory using Pycharm!
